# Ubuntu 14.04 not using alias em1:1 address

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I'm trying to use two IP addresses on a single network device. The device is an onboard NIC and came up as "em0" after initially booting, something I hadn't seen Ubuntu do before.

I'm using a /etc/network/interfaces config file that has worked on previous setups:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1:0
iface em1:0 inet dhcp

auto em1:1
iface em1:1 inet static
address 10.152.187.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.152.187.255
network 10.152.187.0
```

The problem is that the machine comes up with just a "em1" address obtained from DHCP, no em1:0 or em1:1 addresses.

If I run:

```
sudo ifconfig em1:1 10.152.187.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The em1:1 alias comes up just fine and does what I expect.

Comment: I've noticed that on other machines where this setup has worked, not only is the ethernet device named eth0, but there is also a /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file that causes udev to name it -- the problematic machine with em1 does not have this.

Comment: This bug may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biosdevname/+bug/1295873